# Issue with Java script / Jquery validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have one select box and one text box are there. I need to the validation like if both are selected I need alert like "Either select a name or pick the name", If I did not select both i need alert like "Please select a name or pick the name", If I select one of them I need alert like "Thank you for selecting the name". I did it by java script but I did not get the result. Can it be done by using java script / Jquery? Any suggestions

```
    <body>
pick name:
        <select id="ddlView">
            <option value="0">Select</option>
            <option value="1">test1</option>
            <option value="2">test2</option>
            <option value="3">test3</option>
        </select>  
</br>
select name:
<input type= "text" name="raju" id="raju"></input>
        <input type="button" onclick="Validate()" value="select" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function Validate()
            {
                 var name = document.getElementById("raju");
                 var e = document.getElementById("ddlView");
                var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

                var strUser1 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
                if(strUser==0 && (name==null || name== ' '))
                {
                    alert("Please select a name or pick the name");
                }

               else if( (!(strUser==0)) &&(! (name==null || name== ' ')))
                {
                    alert("Either select a name or pick the name");
                }
          else
                {
                     alert("Thank you for selecting the name");
                }
            }
        </script>


    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your same validation using JQuery as you also mentioned:

```
function Validate()
{
    var name = $("#raju").val();
    var selected_name = $('#ddlView :selected').val();

    if(selected_name == 0 && name == "")
    {
        alert("Please select a name or pick the name");
    }
    else if( !(selected_name == 0) && name != "")
    {
        alert("Either select a name or pick the name");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Thank you for selecting the name");
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8242u/)

Comment: You realy don't need to use jQuery here... All you can do without, so why load jQuery library ??

Comment: @Arthur OP asked for it

Comment: Yes in case of javascript can't do it

Comment: That's an odd thing to say. There's nothing JQuery can do that JavaScript can't... JQuery is Javascript.

Comment: So... In case of javascript can't do it **easily** ;)

Comment: Haha, OK fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you get the input, not the value.

Replace var name = document.getElementById("raju"); with var name = document.getElementById("raju").value;

Also, you compare the name with null and blank space. You must compare it with empty string. (name == '')

Answer (score 1):

When you saw on my [Jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/whPtS/1/), I don't use oonclick attribute but a event listener on javascript (realy better for your html)..

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick= function ()
```

One second poitn you have forget tu retrieve .value of you name input (so already return [HTML DOM object] and not null or a value.

```
var name = document.getElementById("raju").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your post was in pure JavaScript, I've decided to answer accordingly. As mentioned, you shouldn't check an empty string for `" "` but rather `''` or `""`. Furthermore, you shouldn't even need to do *that*, since you can simply check `if (str) { // string exists }`. For your `name` variable, you're referring to an HTML element and not it's `string` value. So, all in all (a few errors), nothing majorly wrong here.

I've abstracted this process a tiny bit to give you an idea of how to validate many similar fields without a whole lot of repetitive code.

Note: You should find a way to replace your `inline event handlers` with `unobtrusive` handlers. Example:

```
document.getElementById('someButton').onclick = Validate;
```

That being said, here's a few suggestions:

```
var emptyString = function(str) {
    if (str) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};

var emptySelect = function(sel) {
    if (parseInt(sel) !== 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
};


function Validate() {
    var name = document.getElementById("raju").value;
    var e = document.getElementById("ddlView");
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    switch (true) {
        case (!emptySelect(strUser) && !emptyString(name)):
            alert('Either select a name or pick a name.');
            break;
        case (emptySelect(strUser) && emptyString(name)):
            alert('Please select a name or pick a name.');
            break;
        default:
            // Possibly some default validation
            alert('Thanks for picking a name');
            break;
    }
}
```